# Creating a singup form with popup in wordpress

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

Hey guys i have to make some changes to my e commerce website ..The website is http://www.labskart.com/. The things is that here i want to add a signup option at the top of the website.When a user clicks on the signup button it should come with a popup and asking for
name and email id or with facebook integration like the same way  as the flipcart does.

I have tried to make changes on `header.php` but it didnt do any good ..Am an newbie in wordpress development ..Hope you guys can help me out.

Any suggestions,code samples or any names of plugins must be aprreciated.Thanks in advance

PS: The theme am using is megashop  theme..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it only needs a bit of research. Install a plugin to do that like [WP Modal Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-modal-login/) or search for a better option for you, there's a couple of plugins to do so. Google it by keywords like "wordpress pop up login" and related keywords.

Comment: i have did it like million times bro

Comment: Well that one might work, I'm seeing that they give you a php code and all to put wherever you want in your code for the Login text to appear

`<?php add_modal_login_button( $login_text = 'Login', $logout_text = 'Logout', $logout_url = '', $show_admin = true ); ?>`

Comment: it doesnt have facebook integration

Comment: it doenst show facebook integration .i need a user to be logged in to facebook ..by clicking the fb button as flipcart does

Comment: This one does the job @user3679020 [zM Ajax Login & Register](http://wordpress.org/plugins/zm-ajax-login-register/)

Comment: i have installed it ..but didnt displayed on my website ..i have created a new page as they said ..do you know how to make this visible  on the website ?

Comment: i have done al the things in the plugin manual but it still didnt display

Comment: ..hey i have installed the app but facebook icon doesnt show properly

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at it.

```
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/how-to-display-wordpress-user-registration-form-in-front-end-of-the-website
```

maybe this will provide u form.

Comment: the coding part will be more difficult ..plugins would be easier and possible

Comment: Yeah. Its easier to have plugins but too many plugins make slow WP.